# Trying to end a loop Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Hi I have a pretty basic pong game using the turtle module going and I am trying to add a game end and display a winner, but after adding a break to the main loop it seems to keeps the loop going but broken...

```py
#Main game loop
while score_p_1<5 or score_p_2<5:
    window.update()

    #ball movement
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.vx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.vy)

    #border detection
    if ball.xcor()>300:
        score_p_1 += 1
        ball.setpos(0,0)
        ball.vx *= -1
        score_display.clear()
        score_display.write("Player 1: %d    Player 2: %d" %(score_p_1, score_p_2),move=False,align="center", font=("Arial", 12, "normal"))

    if ball.xcor()<-300:
        score_p_2 += 1
        ball.setpos(0,0)
        ball.vx *= -1
        #need to add to update
        score_display.clear()
        score_display.write("Player 1: %d    Player 2: %d" %(score_p_1, score_p_2),move=False,align="center", font=("Arial", 12, "normal"))

    if ball.ycor()>290:
        ball.vy = -0.05

    if ball.ycor()<-290:
        ball.vy = 0.05

    #colision
    if ball.distance(paddle1) < 25:
        ball.vx = 0.05

    if ball.distance(paddle2) < 25:
        ball.vx = -0.05

    if paddle1.ycor()>=270:
        paddle1.setpos(-250,260)

    if paddle1.ycor()<=-270:
        paddle1.setpos(-250,-260)

    if paddle2.ycor()>=270:
        paddle2.setpos(250,260)

    if paddle2.ycor()<=-270:
        paddle2.setpos(250,-260)

    #Game end
    if score_p_1>=5:
        break

    score_display.clear()
    score_display.write("Player 1 is the Winner!", font=("Arial", 20, "normal"))
```

Comment: You may need to clarify what you mean by "keeps the loop going but broken". Does it display a winner? Do you get an error message? Is there another, outer loop that isn't affected by the break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer to your question per se, but a friendly change in style to avoid repetition and clarify what's happening:

```
# Main game loop.
while score_p_1 < 5 or score_p_2 < 5:
    window.update()

    # Process ball movement.
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.vx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.vy)

    # Scoring detection.
    if ball.xcor() > 300 or ball.xcor() < -300:

        # Who scored?
        if ball.xcor() > 300:
            score_p_1 += 1
        elif ball.xcor() < -300:
            score_p_2 += 1

        # Reset.
        ball.setpos(0, 0)
        ball.vx *= -1
        score_display.clear()
        score_display.write("Player 1: %d    Player 2: %d" %(score_p_1, score_p_2), move=False, align="center", font=("Arial", 12, "normal"))

    # Bouncing against walls.
    if abs(ball.ycor()) > 290:
        ball.vy = -0.05 * np.sign(ball.ycor())

    # Ball/paddle collision.
    for paddle in (paddle1, paddle2):
        if ball.distance(paddle) < 25:
            ball.vx = +0.05 if paddle is paddle1 else -0.05

    # Wall/paddle collision.
    for paddle in (paddle1, paddle2):
        x = -250 if paddle is paddle1 else +250
        y = np.clip(paddle.ycor(), -260, +260) # <- Ensures the paddles stay in [-260, +260].
        paddle.setpos(x, y)

    # Game end. No need for a break, it's already in the while condition.
    if score_p_1 >= 5:
        winner = 1
    elif score_p_2 >= 5:
        winner = 2
    score_display.clear()
    score_display.write(f"Player {winner} is the Winner!", font=("Arial", 20, "normal"))
```

Comment: Not a direct answer no but it did point me in the right direction! and thanks for the formatting tip!!